# Loop of purchased products

Tags: php

I have a function that pickup a purchased products to use for tracking purchased products with analytics.js but the result in the purchase page when I call the function only show the first product without doing a loop.

What I am doing wrong?

```
 public function AddProductosAna($result) {
        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT order_id FROM tborder WHERE cart_id = '$this->id_cesta'");
        $OrderId = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cesta_linea WHERE id_cesta = '$this->id_cesta'");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $producto = $row['id_producto'];

            return <<<HTML

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {

  'id': '{$OrderId['order_id']}',

  'name': '{$producto}',

  'price': '{$row['precio']}',

  'quantity': '{$row['cantidad']}'

});

HTML;

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're writing new code, **_please_ don't use the `mysql_*` functions**. They are old and broken, were deprecated in PHP 5.5, and completely removed in PHP 7.0 (which is so old it no longer even receives active support). Use [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with _prepared statements_ and _parameter binding_ instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/354577 for details.

Comment: He is returning not echoing it will show only one fetch, or I am stupid?

Comment: I call the function like this in other file: <?php echo $pedido->AddProductosAna($result);?> but not loop :(

Comment: As @StupidKid mentioned, your loop will end and return the results on the first iteration since you have a `return` instead of an `echo` in the loop.

Comment: He do not need echo he can store all data in array and then return it. But like this he is getting only one field and return is just closing the loop. So I ain't stupid

Comment: I don't get it, because I don't have real knowledge... Just I try to make this looking other functions in the site by copy-paste and change some strings... So I would need to change the return by echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stupid Kid and Magnus Eriksson indicated, the function should `return` after the wile loop, not inside the while loop.

```
public function AddProductosAna($result) {
        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT order_id FROM tborder WHERE cart_id = '$this->id_cesta'");
        $OrderId = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cesta_linea WHERE id_cesta = '$this->id_cesta'");
        $js = '';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $producto = $row['id_producto'];

            $js .= <<<HTML

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '{$OrderId['order_id']}',
  'name': '{$producto}',
  'price': '{$row['precio']}',
  'quantity': '{$row['cantidad']}'
});

HTML;

        }
        return $js;
    }
```

Comment: I get Notice: Undefined variable: js in /usr/home/.../web/componentes/pedidos/clases/pedidos.class.php on line 951

Comment: OK, I have no copy of line 951, but you do. We need that to help you.

Comment: 951 LINE:   HTML;

Comment: Did you add the initialisation line above the `while` containing `$js = '';` in your code?

Comment: Upss that is, I diden't add that line... Sorry, thanks a lot.